# change .joinedAt format in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a user info command, and i want it to say when a user joined, it kinda works but i want to change the time format, this is the code that gets the join data:

```
message.member.joinedAt
```

i tried using .format('YYYY-MM-DD') right after joinedAt but nothing, this is what it looks like right now (it has italian text for some reason, probably because my discord account is registered in Italy)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a package called [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).
Example:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
moment.utc(<Message>.member.joinedAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Full example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new Discord.Client(); // Define client
const moment = require('moment'); // Define moment
let prefix = 'your-prefix'; // Define your bots prefix

client.on('message', function(message) { // Message event listener
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}info`)) { // If the message starts with the command
        message.channel.send(`<@!${message.author.id}>, you joined this server on ${moment.utc(message.member.joinedAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`);
    }
});
```